# JQuery submit form and output response or error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-forms-plugin

I want to submit form and show message about result.
`update_records` initializes `alert_message` to error message.
If success I expect that its value is changed.
Than `update_records` outputs message.
But the function always alerts "Error submitting form".
What is wrong with this?

The code follows:

```
  function update_records(form_name) {
    var options = {
      async: false,
      alert_message: "Error submitting form",
      success: function(message) {
        this.alert_message = message;
      }
    };
    $('#' + form_name).ajaxSubmit(options);
    alert(options.alert_message);
  }
```

I am newbie in Javascript/JSon/Jquery and I suspect that I misunderstand some basics of mentioned technologies.

**UPDATE:**

I specified `"async:false"` to make execution synchronous (Is it correct?)

I also tried to insert delay between following two lines:

```
$('#' + form_name).ajaxSubmit(options);
pausecomp(1000); // inserted pause
alert(options.alert_message);
```

It also does not resolve the issue.
Code for `pousecomp` follows:

```
  function pausecomp(millis)
  {
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do { curDate = new Date(); }
    while(curDate-date < millis);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The ajaxSubmit's AJAX call is asynchronous - this means that the AJAX request is made out-of-order of usual program execution, and in your program that means that the alert is called before `this.alert_message = message;` has an opportunity to execute. The order of execution is:

1. call `update_records()`
2. make the ajaxSubmit AJAX request, remember to execute the callback function but not now
3. call the `alert(options.alert_message)`
4. when the ajaxSubit request returns data, execute the callback function (which is to set the `this.alert_message` variable)

To have the alert show the correct value, move the code that utilises the AJAX return data (the `alert()`) to the `success()` function - that what the success function is for.

Comment: In fact I need to store info about success after execution of `update_records()` function. And I would like to find the way to do so.
In the example in question this is by storing messsage.

Comment: add `alert(message);` in your success function. Use this data to note down the data values returned from your server-side form on success and failure. Check the return value with `if` in JQuery, and respond with an `alert()` accordingly. Don't forget to remove the `alert(message);` debug :)

Comment: I just found workaround, I changed from "this.alert_message = message;" to "options.alert_message = message;" but I hate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#' + form_name).ajaxSubmit(options);
```

As the AJAX acronym suggest this call is asynchronous so your `alert(options.alert_message);`
 is called before the success callback is called thats why you always get an alert with error message although an ajax call may complete successfully you could try something like this instead:

```
 function update_records(form_name) {

    var options = {
      async: false,
      alert_message: "Error submitting form",
      success: function(message) {
        alert(message);
      },
      error : function(){
        alert(this.alert_message);
      }
    };
    $('#' + form_name).ajaxSubmit(options);

  }
```

Comment: I specified that call is synchronous (async: false). Or I missed something?